# value has been overrite in nested forLoop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I am not sure what' wrong with my code, value has been override in the nested for-loop, please help me debug following code. var1 is an array that contains another array called list. Var2 is also an array, and each var2.data is equal to the var1. I tried to setup the list.id = var2.index of each var2.data, but for some reason that all the list.id inside of var2 are equal 2, seems like that value has been override. Please see below:

```
    let var1 = [{
        'name': 'name1',
        'list': [{
            id: 0,
            a: "test1",
            b: 'test2'
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            a: "aac",
            b: 'test2'
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            a: "aad",
            b: 'test2'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'name': 'name2',
        'list': [{
            id: 0,
            a: "test1",
            b: 'test2'
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            a: "aac",
            b: 'test2'
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            a: "aad",
            b: 'test2'
          },
        ]
      }
    ];

    let var2 = [{
        claim: 'claim1',
        ifn: '1',
        data: []
      },
      {
        claim: 'claim2',
        ifn: '2',
        data: []
      },
      {
        claim: 'claim3',
        ifn: '3',
        data: []
      },
    ]

    var2.forEach((item, i) => {
      var1.forEach(list => {
        list.list.forEach(val => {
          val.id = i;
        })
        item.data = list;
      })
    })
   console.log(var2)
```

I would like to have that each list.id equal the index of var2, like below, really not sure how to make this code work, please help~

```
var2 = [
{ claim:'claim1',ifn:'1',
  data:
      [{
        'name':'name1',
        'list':[
            {id:0,a:"test1",b:'test2'},
            {id:0,a:"aac",b:'test2'},
            {id:0,a:"aad",b:'test2'},
               ]
        },
        {
         'name':'name2',
         'list':[
                {id:0,a:"test1",b:'test2'},
                {id:0,a:"aac",b:'test2'},
                {id:0,a:"aad",b:'test2'},
               ]
      }]
},
{ claim:'claim2',ifn:'2',
  data:
      [{
        'name':'name1',
        'list':[
            {id:1,a:"test1",b:'test2'},
            {id:1,a:"aac",b:'test2'},
            {id:1,a:"aad",b:'test2'},
         ]
        },
    {
    'name':'name2',
        'list':[
                {id:1,a:"test1",b:'test2'},
                {id:1,a:"aac",b:'test2'},
                {id:1,a:"aad",b:'test2'},
               ]
      }]
},
{ claim:'claim3',ifn:'3',
  data:[{
        'name':'name1',
        'list':[
                {id:2,a:"test1",b:'test2'},
                {id:2,a:"aac",b:'test2'},
                {id:2,a:"aad",b:'test2'},
                ]
        },
        {
        'name':'name2',
        'list':[
            {id:2,a:"test1",b:'test2'},
                {id:2,a:"aac",b:'test2'},
                {id:2,a:"aad",b:'test2'},
               ]
     }]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @lin - welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question as written is a little difficult to parse-- you might want to review [ask] for tips on crafting a well-formed question.  This will help in drawing high quality answers to your post.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Your lower object seems to have semicolons in it, which is invaild syntax, it's not entirely clear what the structure you're actually looking for is.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear structure, I had clear up a little bit, hope it will be easier to understand.

Comment: How do you check for merging? Same index will merge data?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want every `data` value in your var2 to point to var1. The following loop will do that:

```
var2.forEach(item => item.data = var1);
```

However, because each item points to the same object, it means that if you change any `data` item inside var2, it will change all of them.

If you need the copies to be unique, you can make a new copy with something like this:

```
const getVar1 = () =>  [
  {
    'name': 'name1',
    'list':  [
      {
        id: 0,
        a: "test1",
        b: 'test2'
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        a: "aac",
        b: 'test2'
      },
      {
        id: 0,
        a: "aad",
        b: 'test2'
      },
    ]
  },
  ...
];
```

and then you can use it like so:

```
var2.forEach(item => item.data = getVar1())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need create new copy. But desire result you can use this code -

```
for (var i = 0; i < var2.length; i++) {

  var el = var2[i], arr = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < var1.length; j++) {

    var o = var1[j];

    for (var k = 0; k < o.list.length; k++) {
      var ob = o.list[k];
      console.log(ob);
      ob.id = i;
    }

    arr.push(o);
  }

  el.data = arr;
}
```